# Errors when uploading custom data fusion plugin jar and json files

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to upload a custom plugin to DataFusion.
I have both files JAR and JSON. I will show codes for both below:

1. HTTP-batchsource.jar

```
@Plugin(type = BatchSource.PLUGIN_TYPE)
@Name(HttpBatchSource.NAME)
@Description("Read data from HTTP endpoint.")
public class HttpBatchSource extends BatchSource<NullWritable, BasePage, StructuredRecord> {
  static final String NAME = "HTTP";

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpBatchSource.class);

  private final HttpBatchSourceConfig config;
  private Schema schema;

  public HttpBatchSource(HttpBatchSourceConfig config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  @Override
  public void configurePipeline(PipelineConfigurer pipelineConfigurer) {
    config.validate(); // validate when macros not yet substituted
    config.validateSchema();

    pipelineConfigurer.getStageConfigurer().setOutputSchema(config.getSchema());
  }

  @Override
  public void prepareRun(BatchSourceContext context) {
    config.validate(); // validate when macros are already substituted
    config.validateSchema();

    schema = config.getSchema();

    LineageRecorder lineageRecorder = new LineageRecorder(context, config.referenceName);
    lineageRecorder.createExternalDataset(schema);
    lineageRecorder.recordRead("Read", String.format("Read from HTTP '%s'", config.getUrl()),
      Preconditions.checkNotNull(schema.getFields()).stream()
        .map(Schema.Field::getName)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    context.setInput(Input.of(config.referenceName, new HttpInputFormatProvider(config)));
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(BatchRuntimeContext context) throws Exception {
    this.schema = config.getSchema();
    super.initialize(context);
  }

  @Override
  public void transform(KeyValue<NullWritable, BasePage> input, Emitter<StructuredRecord> emitter) {
    BasePage page = input.getValue();
    while (page.hasNext()) {
      PageEntry pageEntry = page.next();

      if (!pageEntry.isError()) {
        emitter.emit(pageEntry.getRecord());
      } else {
        InvalidEntry<StructuredRecord> invalidEntry = pageEntry.getError();
        switch (pageEntry.getErrorHandling()) {
          case SKIP:
            LOG.warn(invalidEntry.getErrorMsg());
            break;
          case SEND:
            emitter.emitError(invalidEntry);
            break;
          case STOP:
            throw new RuntimeException(invalidEntry.getErrorMsg());
          default:
            throw new UnexpectedFormatException(
              String.format("Unknown error handling strategy '%s'", config.getErrorHandling()));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the HTTP-batchsource.json

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "spec-version": "1.5"
    },
    "configuration-groups": [{
            "label": "General",
            "properties": [{
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Reference Name",
                    "name": "referenceName"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "URL",
                    "name": "url"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "select",
                    "label": "HTTP Method",
                    "name": "httpMethod",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "values": [
                            "GET",
                            "POST",
                            "PUT",
                            "DELETE",
                            "HEAD"
                        ],
                        "default": "GET"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "keyvalue",
                    "label": "Headers",
                    "name": "headers",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "showDelimiter": "false"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textarea",
                    "name": "requestBody",
                    "label": "Request Body",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "rows": "5"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Format",
            "properties": [{
                    "widget-type": "select",
                    "label": "Format",
                    "name": "format",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "values": [
                            "json",
                            "xml",
                            "tsv",
                            "csv",
                            "text",
                            "blob"
                        ],
                        "default": "json"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "JSON/XML Result Path",
                    "name": "resultPath"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "keyvalue",
                    "label": "JSON/XML Fields Mapping",
                    "name": "fieldsMapping",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "showDelimiter": "false"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "radio-group",
                    "label": "CSV Skip First Row",
                    "name": "csvSkipFirstRow",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "layout": "inline",
                        "default": "false",
                        "options": [{
                                "id": "true",
                                "label": "true"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "false",
                                "label": "false"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "OAuth2",
            "properties": [{
                    "widget-type": "toggle",
                    "label": "OAuth2 Enabled",
                    "name": "oauth2Enabled",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "default": "false",
                        "on": {
                            "label": "True",
                            "value": "true"
                        },
                        "off": {
                            "label": "False",
                            "value": "false"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Auth URL",
                    "name": "authUrl"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Token URL",
                    "name": "tokenUrl"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Client ID",
                    "name": "clientId"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "password",
                    "label": "Client Secret",
                    "name": "clientSecret"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Scopes",
                    "name": "scopes"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Refresh Token",
                    "name": "refreshToken"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Basic Authentication",
            "properties": [{
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Username",
                    "name": "username"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "password",
                    "label": "Password",
                    "name": "password"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "HTTP Proxy",
            "properties": [{
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Proxy URL",
                    "name": "proxyUrl"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Username",
                    "name": "proxyUsername"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "password",
                    "label": "Password",
                    "name": "proxyPassword"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Error Handling",
            "properties": [{
                    "widget-type": "keyvalue-dropdown",
                    "label": "HTTP Errors Handling",
                    "name": "httpErrorsHandling",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "default": "2..:Success,.*:Fail",
                        "showDelimiter": "false",
                        "dropdownOptions": [
                            "Success",
                            "Fail",
                            "Skip",
                            "Send to error",
                            "Retry and fail",
                            "Retry and skip",
                            "Retry and send to error"
                        ],
                        "key-placeholder": "HTTP Status Code Regex"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "radio-group",
                    "label": "Non-HTTP Error Handling",
                    "name": "errorHandling",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "layout": "inline",
                        "default": "stopOnError",
                        "options": [{
                                "id": "stopOnError",
                                "label": "Stop on error"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "sendToError",
                                "label": "Send to error"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "skipOnError",
                                "label": "Skip on error"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "radio-group",
                    "label": "Retry Policy",
                    "name": "retryPolicy",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "layout": "inline",
                        "default": "exponential",
                        "options": [{
                                "id": "exponential",
                                "label": "Exponential"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "linear",
                                "label": "Linear"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "number",
                    "label": "Linear Retry Interval",
                    "name": "linearRetryInterval",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "min": "0",
                        "default": "30"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "number",
                    "label": "Max Retry Duration",
                    "name": "maxRetryDuration",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "min": "0",
                        "default": "600"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "number",
                    "label": "Connect Timeout",
                    "name": "connectTimeout",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "min": "0",
                        "default": "120"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "number",
                    "label": "Read Timeout",
                    "name": "readTimeout",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "min": "0",
                        "default": "120"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Pagination",
            "properties": [{
                    "widget-type": "select",
                    "label": "Pagination Type",
                    "name": "paginationType",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "values": [
                            "None",
                            "Link in response header",
                            "Link in response body",
                            "Token in response body",
                            "Increment an index",
                            "Custom"
                        ],
                        "default": "None"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Start Index",
                    "name": "startIndex",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "placeholder": "For pagination type \"Increment an index\""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Max Index",
                    "name": "maxIndex",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "placeholder": "For pagination type \"Increment an index\""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Index Increment",
                    "name": "indexIncrement",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "placeholder": "For pagination type \"Increment an index\""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Next Page JSON/XML Field Path",
                    "name": "nextPageFieldPath",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "placeholder": "For pagination type \"Link in response body\""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Next Page Token Path",
                    "name": "nextPageTokenPath",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "placeholder": "For pagination type \"Token in response body\""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Next Page Url Parameter",
                    "name": "nextPageUrlParameter",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "placeholder": "For pagination type \"Token in response body\""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "python-editor",
                    "label": "Custom Pagination Python Code",
                    "name": "customPaginationCode",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "placeholder": "def get_next_page_url(url, page, headers):\n    \"\"\"\n    Based on previous page data generates next page url, when \"Custom pagination\" is enabled.\n    Returns 'None' if no more pages to load \n\n    Args:\n        url (string): previous page url\n        page (string): a body of previous page\n        headers (dict): a dictionary of headers from previous page\n\n    \"\"\"\n    return \"https://next-page-url.com\""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "number",
                    "label": "Wait Time Between Pages (milliseconds)",
                    "name": "waitTimeBetweenPages",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "min": "0",
                        "default": "0"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "SSL/TLS",
            "properties": [{
                    "widget-type": "toggle",
                    "label": "Verify HTTPS Trust Certificates",
                    "name": "verifyHttps",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "default": "true",
                        "on": {
                            "label": "True",
                            "value": "true"
                        },
                        "off": {
                            "label": "False",
                            "value": "false"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Keystore File",
                    "name": "keystoreFile"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "select",
                    "label": "Keystore Type",
                    "name": "keystoreType",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "default": "Java KeyStore (JKS)",
                        "values": [
                            "Java KeyStore (JKS)",
                            "Java Cryptography Extension KeyStore (JCEKS)",
                            "PKCS #12"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "password",
                    "label": "Keystore Password",
                    "name": "keystorePassword"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Keystore Key Algorithm",
                    "name": "keystoreKeyAlgorithm",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "default": "SunX509"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "TrustStore File",
                    "name": "trustStoreFile"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "select",
                    "label": "TrustStore Type",
                    "name": "trustStoreType",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "default": "Java KeyStore (JKS)",
                        "values": [
                            "Java KeyStore (JKS)",
                            "Java Cryptography Extension KeyStore (JCEKS)",
                            "PKCS #12"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "password",
                    "label": "TrustStore Password",
                    "name": "trustStorePassword"
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "TrustStore Key Algorithm",
                    "name": "trustStoreKeyAlgorithm",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "default": "SunX509"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "csv",
                    "label": "Transport Protocols",
                    "name": "transportProtocols",
                    "widget-attributes": {
                        "default": "TLSv1.2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget-type": "textbox",
                    "label": "Cipher Suites",
                    "name": "cipherSuites"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "emit-errors": true,
    "outputs": [{
        "name": "schema",
        "label": "schema",
        "widget-type": "schema",
        "widget-attributes": {
            "schema-types": [
                "boolean",
                "int",
                "long",
                "float",
                "double",
                "bytes",
                "string",
                "array",
                "record",
                "map",
                "union"
            ],
            "schema-default-type": "string",
            "property-watch": "format"
        }
    }],
    "filters": [{
            "name": "Proxy authentication",
            "condition": {

            },
            "show": [{
                    "name": "proxyUsername",
                    "type": "property"
                },
                {
                    "name": "proxyPassword",
                    "type": "property"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Increment an index",
            "condition": {
                "property": "paginationType",
                "operator": "equal to",
                "value": "Increment an index"
            },
            "show": [{
                    "name": "startIndex",
                    "type": "property"
                },
                {
                    "name": "maxIndex",
                    "type": "property"
                },
                {
                    "name": "indexIncrement",
                    "type": "property"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Token in Response Body",
            "condition": {
                "property": "paginationType",
                "operator": "equal to",
                "value": "Token in response body"
            },
            "show": [{
                    "name": "nextPageTokenPath",
                    "type": "property"
                },
                {
                    "name": "nextPageUrlParameter",
                    "type": "property"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Link in response body",
            "condition": {
                "property": "paginationType",
                "operator": "equal to",
                "value": "Link in response body"
            },
            "show": [{
                "name": "nextPageFieldPath",
                "type": "property"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Custom pagination",
            "condition": {
                "property": "paginationType",
                "operator": "equal to",
                "value": "Custom"
            },
            "show": [{
                "name": "customPaginationCode",
                "type": "property"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Pagination none",
            "condition": {
                "property": "paginationType",
                "operator": "equal to",
                "value": "None"
            },
            "show": [{
                "name": "waitTimeBetweenPages",
                "type": "property"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "OAuth 2 disabled",
            "condition": {
                "property": "oauth2Enabled",
                "operator": "equal to",
                "value": "false"
            },
            "show": [{
                    "name": "username",
                    "type": "property"
                },
                {
                    "name": "password",
                    "type": "property"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "OAuth 2 enabled",
            "condition": {
                "property": "oauth2Enabled",
                "operator": "equal to",
                "value": "true"
            },
            "show": [{
                    "name": "authUrl",
                    "type": "property"
                },
                {
                    "name": "tokenUrl",
                    "type": "property"
                },
                {
                    "name": "clientId",
                    "type": "property"
                },
                {
                    "name": "clientSecret",
                    "type": "property"
                },
                {
                    "name": "scopes",
                    "type": "property"
                },
                {
                    "name": "refreshToken",
                    "type": "property"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "JSON/XML Formatting",
            "condition": {
                "expression": "format == 'json' || format == 'xml'"
            },
            "show": [{
                    "name": "resultPath",
                    "type": "property"
                },
                {
                    "name": "fieldsMapping",
                    "type": "property"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "CSV Formatting",
            "condition": {
                "property": "format",
                "operator": "equal to",
                "value": "csv"
            },
            "show": [{
                "name": "csvSkipFirstRow",
                "type": "property"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I upload the `.jar` to data fusion it works fine, however, when I try upload the `.json` too it gives me the error:

> "Invalid plugin JSON. Please specify parent artifacts." or "Plugin configuration should be in JSON format"

Answer (score 0):

Once you run `mvn clean package -DskipTests` there will be jar and json created in target/ directory of the plugin repo. That jar and json should be used to deploy the plugin.